CSS to put 4 Divisions at the bottom of the Page
I'm trying to use CSS to place 2 or more div tags below some content. I want to keep the div's in order and place them always show at the bottom of the page. I cannot implicitly style each tag because I won't know how many there are up front because they are created dynamically, so I was hoping to apply on CSS class/tag to each div and have it automatically apply to all of them.
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .myCssClass {
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='myCssClass'>My div 1 is above the content below but want it below it.</div>
    <div class='myCssClass'>My div 2 is above the content below but want it below it.</div>
    <div class='myCssClass'>My div 3 is above the content below but want it below it.</div>
    <div class='myCssClass'>My div 4 is above the content below but want it below it.</div>

    <p>My content is below the 'divs' tags above, but I want to place all the div's below this content, in order. But, I won't know up front how many div's there are because they are created dymaically</p>
</body>
</html>



Using Flex in body  and margin for myCssClass  can solve this issue:
<head>

<style>
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
}
.content {
flex: 1;
}
.myCssClass {
margin-top: auto;
}
</style>
</head>


Wow. Easy enought Thanks!

@ptownbro, My pleasure,
